# get posts by tag to showing in a widget

Tags: query, tags, get-post

Hi there dear developers!
i make a widget in my wordpress theme to show 5 last video-based posts in that. and my video posts have a 'video' tag. how i can query that posts by tag to showing there?
thanks.

Comment: what code have you tried to write by yourself to do that?

Comment: i don't know what i must write for that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to go through:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

So using `tag` parameter in `WP_Query`, you can get posts tagged to 'video' tag.

Use `orderby` and `posts_per_page` to get last 5 video posts.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
//your code to display posts
endwhile;
```

Haven't tested the code, so watch out for typos.

Comment: RTFM kind of answers are not very useful :(. If you are going to answer such a lazy question, at least you can try to give a fuller solution

Comment: Sorry, still new to answering.....hope edit helps :)

Comment: but it's NOT WORKED :( edit: there was an error in names and it's solved.